# Open specific activity with NFC in Android and launch as separate task

Tags: android, nfc

Today I managed to write a small app with three pages:

1. Start-Page with Server Login
2. Menu Page
3. NFC Page for NFC-Reading

I also managed to read nfc tags and to print out the information I got from the nfc tag but there are a few questions I have now:

1. When I am at my Menu Page and place the Tag to read the NFC my 
   Start-Page appears automatically but I want my NFC Page to appear
   automatically. How can I do that?
2. I made my app to start automatically when an nfc tag is placed near
   my smartphone. How can I make the app appear in the list of active 
   and started apps? When I start my app manually it appears in the list 
   of all apps running. If I start my ap automatically using a nfc tag
   it does not appear in the list of all apps running.

Comment: are you using nfc [android application record](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar) to start your app ?

Comment: yes, exactly that! But with 'TECH_DISCOVERED' instead of 'NDEF_DISCOVERED'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To always open your NFC Page when tapped, move `TECH_DISCOVERED` intent-filter under NFC page activity entry.

  ```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
  </intent-filter>
  ```
- use [`singleTask` launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManifestForTasks) for your NFC Page activity

  ```
      <activity android:name=".NFCPage"
          android:label="@string/nfc_page"
          android:launchMode="singleTask">
  ```

Comment: Thank you, simply moving the intent-filter to the NFCPage section and adding launchMode solved both problems.

Comment: Why should I use TECH_DISCOVERED and not NDEF_DISCOVERED?